# Swifte - Xcode Protocol confusion

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've started working with protocols but I ran into some trouble.

I made my protocol:

```
protocol DataSource: class {
    func getSpeedFromViewController(sender: GameScene) -> Float
    func addPoints(pointsToAdd: Int, sender: GameScene)
    func removePoints(pointsToRemove: Int, sender: GameScene)
}
```

In my Gamescene:

```
// protocol
weak var dataSource: DataSource?
```

In my GameViewController:

```
// protocol conformation
scene.dataSource = self

// first one, getspeed
func getSpeedFromViewController(sender: GameScene) -> Float{
    return Slider.value
}

// add Points
func addPoints(pointsToAdd: Int, sender: GameScene){
    Man.addPoints(pointsToAdd)
}

//remove Points
func removePoints(pointsToRemove: Int, sender: GameScene){
    Man.removePoints(pointsToRemove)

}
```

now getSpeedFromViewController worked just perfect, I call it in the scene, get the speed and everything is great.

But I cant get the others functions to work. I tried so many things, it just doesn't work.

If I try to use them :

```
DataSource.addPoints(10,sender: self)
```

I get the Error "Extra argument `sender`in call.
If I remove the "sender:", I get Extra argument in call.
If I remove everything and just do

addPoints(self)

I get "Cannot invoke `addPoints` with argument of type `(GameScene)`

If I remove the Int passing they work ofc. So the Problem is it just won't let me pass in anything else then the sender though the protocol. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I know this sounds odd, but I've noticed swift is picky about white space.  try putting a space between the comma and sender.

Comment: sadly that changes nothing.

Comment: does your GameViewController inherit your protocol DataSource?  since that is where you are defining them? class GameViewController: UIViewController, DataSource

Comment: yes it does, sry for not adding that to the code snipplets :                        class GameViewController: UIViewController, DataSource {

Answer (score 1):

omg i cant belive it, im retarded. so the problem was that i was using "DataSource" which is linking to the protocol. I have to use "dataSource" which links to the var. I didnt realize that i was using the wrong one because i named them so poorly. Anyways thanks for the help guys.